# Dependency, not waiting until finished (Cocos2d/Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Here is my code:

```
 NSOperationQueue * que = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSBlockOperation * number1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    CCActionRotateTo * rotLeft = [CCActionRotateBy actionWithDuration:4.2 angle:-70];

    [_claw runAction:rotLeft];
}];
NSBlockOperation * number2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    CCActionRotateTo * rotRight = [CCActionRotateBy actionWithDuration:4.2 angle:120];


    [_claw runAction:rotRight];
}];
[number2 addDependency:number1];
[que addOperations:@[number1,number2] waitUntilFinished:YES];
```

But I can't figure out why number 2 is executing before number1 and not waiting until the first one is done, any help would be appreciated =)

Comment: errrr ... [_claw runAction:[CCActionSequence actions:rotLeft,rotRight,nil]];   or am i missing something fundamental here ?

Comment: Thx YvesLeBorg, that fixed it. Didn't even think about doing it that way, guess I'm still kinda new to cocos2d

Comment: take a peek at the API docs ... there are lots of goodies in cocos 3.x.

Comment: Defiantly will now, especially since I wasted so much time figuring out this problem.

Comment: operation queues for actions equals apples and oranges ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're performing operations that affect your UI, I think you need to use `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`.

```
 NSOperationQueue * que = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
```

By default when you `init` the `NSOperationQueue` it will use a background thread, which may cause your UI updates to be delayed/never run.

Comment: Not sure I quite understand what you are trying to say mate.

How would I implement the [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]?

Comment: +1 anything that could affect coco's objects must run on the main thread (openGL will bite you). Cocos has toys for doing this safely (see my comment on the question).